# Which code is more CPU/memory efficient when used with a Garbage Collected language?

Tags: java, c#, garbage-collection

I have these two dummy pieces of code (let's consider they are written in either Java or C#, all variables are local):

Code 1:

```
int a;
int b = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    a = 10;
    b += i;

    // a lot of more code that doesn't involve assigning new values to "a"
}
```

Code 2:

```
int b = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    int a = 10;
    b += i;

    // a lot of more code that doesn't involve assigning new values to "a"
}
```

At first glance I would say both codes consume the same amount of memory, but Code 1 is more CPU efficient because it creates and allocates variable `a` just once.
Then I read that Garbage Collectors are extremely efficient to the point that Code 2 would be the more Memory (and CPU?) efficient: keeping variable `a` inside the loop makes it belongs to Gen0, so it would be garbage collected before variable `b`.

So, when used with a Garbage Collected language, Code 2 is the more efficient. Am I right?

Comment: There's no garbage collection going on here.

Comment: What's the point of repeatedly re-assigning `a`? Also note that these two bits are quite different (the second one has no `a` variable outside the loop, the first one does).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Clearly it's just a toy example; the general idea is whether or not it makes sense to have variables scoped within a loop, or if they should be pulled outside of the loop (even if not used outside of the loop) as an optimization.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as Servy said: it is a toy sample to illustrate an optimization problem

Comment: Usually it's best to make an example at least vaguely realistic, rather than doing something you would never really do.

Comment: It would be better to actually use variable a (as it would in a realistic example). Then the compiler and everything else behind will work different. As it is you might be unable to infer anything useful from this unrealistic example.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A few points:

- ints (and other primitives) are never allocated on heap. They live directly on the thread stack, "allocation" and "deallocation" are simple moves of a pointer, and happen once (when the function is entered, and immediately after return), regardless of scope.
- primitives, that are accessed often, are usually stored in a register for speed, again, regardless of scope.
- in your case `a` (and possibly, `b` as well, together with the whole loop) will be "optimized away", the optimizer is smart enough to detect a situation when a variable value changes, but is never read, and skip redundant operations. Or, if there is code that actually looks at `a`, but does not modify it, it will likely be replaced by the optimizer by a constant value of "10", that'll just appear inline everywhere where `a` is referenced.
- New objects (if you did something like `String a = new String("foo")` for example instead of int) are **always** allocated in young generation, and only get transferred into old gen after  they survive a few minor collections. This means that, for most of the cases, when an object is allocated inside a function, and never referenced from outside, it will never make it to the old gen regardless of its exact scope, unless your heap structure desperately needs tuning.
- As pointed out in the comment, sometimes the VM might decide to allocate a large object directly in the old gen (this is true for java too, not just .net), so the point above only apply in most cases, but not *always*. However, in relation to this question, this does not make any difference, because if the decision is made to allocate an object in old gen, it is made without regard of the scope of its initial reference anyway.

From performance and memory standpoint your two snippets are identical. From the readability perspective though, it is always a good idea to declare all variables in the narrowest possible scope.

Comment: For the current .NET implementation of the GC and large object will be allocated on the large-object-heap, which is effectively Gen2 (the highest generation). So allocation doesn't always go the the youngest generation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's a good point (and it is true for java too, not just .net). Thanks for pointing it out! I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: No, the LOH is not effectively the same as Gen2.  The LOH is not part of the generational compaction process at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right that large objects get allocated in a different memory region. But objects in it will only be considered for collection during a full (Gen2) GC. `GC.GetGeneration(new byte[100*1000])` is 2.

Answer (score 18):

Before the code in snippet 2 is actually executed it's going to end up being transformed to look like the code in snippet 1 behind the scenes (whether it be a compiler or runtime).  As a result, the performance of the two snippets is going to be identical, as they'll compile into functionally the same code at some point.

Note that for very short lived variables it's actually quite possible for them to not have memory allocated for them at all.  They may well be stored entirely in a register, involving 0 memory allocation.

Comment: Either the compiler or the jit?

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah, somewhere in the stack.  For the purposes of this question, it shouldn't much matter which.

Comment: I agree, how it happens *doesn't matter* and changes from distribution to distribution :)

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler completely delete the "int a = 10"? (I know it is a toy example) If there weren't any compiler optimizations and the code was compiled exactly as is, I would guess Code 2 is worse no?

Comment: @Dzyann In the exact example given the variable is not used in either case, and so would be elided entirely in both cases.  Assuming the variable is read from, as appears to be the intent of the question, the answer applies.  Regardless, the code snippets still don't actually differ.